# Does $x^3 \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$ have any solutions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

My gut instinct is that it does not, but I am unsure of how to show this... and I think the $x^3$ is what is causing me trouble in figuring this out. I have attempted to rewrite it using the definition of divisibility and proceeding to $x^3-6=11k$, where $k$ is an integer. However, at this point I am unsure of how to proceed. What would the next step be, or is this the wrong way to approach this problem?

Comment: All you have to do is try the numbers $\{0,\cdots, 10\}$.

Comment: Note:  since $3\,\nmid 10$, cubing is an automorphism of the units $\pmod {11}$, so you know in advance that there is a unique solution.

Comment: **Hint:**  $3^3 = 27 = 22 + 5  \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$ and $-6 \equiv 5 \pmod {11}$

Comment: Thanks. I just didn't know if there was a different way besides trying out all of those values. I guess maybe it is a lesson in not making things more difficult than they need to be.

Comment: Drawing up operation tables for operations in algebraic structures (like the operation $x \mapsto x^3$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{11}$) is relaxing and instructive. Don't despise calculation and tabulation!

Comment: $f(x) = x^3$ is a bijection from the integers modulo 11 to the integers modulo 11.  So there must be an element that maps to  $6.$

Comment: @Doug That's already exploited my answer, where I use its inverse $\,f^{-1}(x) = x^{-3}\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is 
$$x=8 \mod{11}$$
We know it is unique by finding the values of $x^3 \mod{11}$ for $0 \le x \lt 11$ as we can reduce all other values of $x$ I to this range.

Comment: Is there a typo. where it says "$x$ I to"?

Comment: Is there any math?  Pulling the answer out of a hat is ok for magic, but not for mathematics.

Answer (score 2):

Make  a table of cubes. As it is obvious that $0,1,-1$ are not solutions, we'll make a table for the other values. Note that $6\equiv -5\mod 11$:
\begin{array}{l|rrrr|}
x&\pm2&\pm3&\pm 4&\pm 5 \cr
\hline
x^2&4&-2&5&3\cr
x^3& \mp3&\pm 5&\mp2&\pm4 \cr
\hline
\end{array}

so the solutions are $\;x\equiv -3\;\text{ (or }8)\mod 11$.

Comment: Simpler to cube the inverse of $\,6,\,$ see my answer.

Comment: Ingenious! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$\bmod 11\!:\ \left[x^{\large 3}\equiv 6\right]^{\large -3}\!\!\!\!\!\!\Longrightarrow\, \underbrace{x^{\large -9}}_{\Large x}\equiv  \left(\dfrac{1}6\right)^{\large 3}\!\!\equiv \left(\dfrac{12}6\right)^{\large 3}\!\!\equiv 8$

Comment: Notice $\large \,x^{\large 10}\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\, x^{\large -9}\equiv x\ $ for $\large \,x\not\equiv 0\,$ by little Fermat.

Comment: What does it mean to raise an equivalence to the power $-3$? I am amazed that you think the OP will be able to follow your answer without some narrative to explain the steps.

Comment: @Rob $\large \left [a\equiv b\right]^{\large n}$ means raise $\,a\equiv b\,$ to power $\,n\,$ to get $\,\large a^{\large n}\equiv b^{\large n}.\,$ That should be clear from the context (if not then simply inquire in a comment).

Comment: Using notations that are only understandable by someone with enough mathematically maturity to apply the "what else could it mean" argument is deeply unhelpful. I have never seen that notation before in many years of perusing the mathematical literature. The OP here is a beginner. Ny comment is about the usefulness of your answer to a beginner.

Comment: @Rob  We'll have to (strongly) disagree about that. The presentation was chosen specifically to help students discover the essence of the matter on their own.

Comment: You are using notation of your own devising. You should not be assuming that it is universally understood.

Comment: It is most certainly not of "my own devising", e.g. it has  been used on many blackboards at MIT and Harvard (and not only by me).

Comment: I'm assuming that the OP is trying to learn mathematics at his or her institution using widely available sources of information. The notation that you justify by an appeal to the blackboards of MIT and Harvard is not well-known to us lesser mortals who have not studied at those US ivory towers and who confine our notion of what is well-known to the mathematical literature.

Comment: @Rob I'm surprised that you have never encountered it. What is in the "literature" is not the same as what is on blackboards. But this is not the place to debate notation. In any case, this is not a *static* paper or book. One can inquire in comments about anything that is unfamiliar. As you can see, I typically respond quickly.

Comment: @Rob Inspired by your remarks, I'm going to call them "ivory tower powers" in the future!